# Can nested NavHosts both be the default nav host (defaultNavHost="true")?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I implemented a navigation structure using two nested `NavHostFragments`s. I want the back button to first pop the navigation stack of the child `Fragment`'s navigation graph, and then once back to the start, pop the parent `Fragment`'s graph. This behaviour works when I set `app:defaultNavHost="true"` for both the parent and child `FragmentContainerView`s.

But according to the Android documentation:

> The `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute ensures that your `NavHostFragment` intercepts the system Back button. Note that only one `NavHost` can be the default. If you have multiple hosts in the same layout (two-pane layouts, for example), be sure to specify only one default `NavHost`.

Is this rule still applicable when using nested `NavHost`s?
What problems could I run into when setting `defaultNavHost="true"` for multiple/nested `NavHost`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limitation of 'only one `defaultNavHost`' only applies to two `NavHostFragment`s in the same `FragmentManager` (i.e., siblings). Nesting them is totally fine.